# Check if NSKeyedUnarchiver is returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver

I need to do an if statement that is based on weather a variable has been archived. I do this as follows:

```
if NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(encodedNotif) == nil {
}
```

But if 'encodedNotif' is nil I get an:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

error.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check it, simply speaking:

```
if endodedNotif != nil {
  if NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(encodedNotif) == nil {
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work because encodedNotif is initially nil and is assigned a value when a button is clicked and if encodedNotif is nil.

Comment: Your code fails since you try to pass a nil pointer to the unarchiver. Hence the error message.

Comment: @AlexCatchpole: You need to check for nil before calling `unarchiveObjectWithData`